# Another expression for "Introduction"

Tags: expressions, synonyms

I'm writing a work, and one of the initial chapters is an introduction. However, I strongly dislike calling that chapter just "Introduction". I think it's too short, too general... I'm looking for another expression that could convey a similar information. Some expressions came to my mind like "The lie of the land" or "A landscape view"... However, these expressions are not so formal, and clearly not so immediately interpretable as introduction.

What other expressions could I use?

Comment: Is this fiction? Are you looking for a title for the "introduction chapter"?

Comment: If you google synonyms for **start**, you'll come across several possibilities, such as **inception, onset, emergence, & kickoff**, which may suit your purpose.

Comment: **Foreword** is commonly used, but also short and also general.  *Setting the scene* might work for you.  Is there a phrase that ties in with what your work is about that could be used?

Comment: Would **prologue** or  **preamble** fit?

Comment: Or **preface**. (A *foreword*, as previously mentioned, is normally written by somebody *other* than the author.) Really, any thesaurus could help.

Comment: "A landscape view" sounds like you want to provide a summary of what you intend to say in the rest of the work. If so, you could use the term **synopsis**.

Comment: @AIQ 1.No, it's not fiction. 2. Yes